# Difference between 'mandrill-api' gem and 'mandrill_mailer' gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actionmailer, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm having some difficulty finding a clear explanation regarding the differences between the official '[mandrill-api](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.ruby.html)' gem and the '[mandrill_mailer](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/mandrill_mailer/0.4.13/frames)' gem, even after thoroughly reading through their documentation.

If my goal is to send transactional emails (such as signup welcome email), as well as weekly digest emails that are customized to the user based on their site activity, will just one of these gems work? Or do I need both to accomplish this? I also want to use MailChimp integrated templates in Mandrill.

Right now I've been using ActionMailer, and I saw that by using the mandrill_mailer gem I can do something like:

```
class UserMailer < MandrillMailer::TemplateMailer
```

and specify which template I want to use, can I do the same thing in the official mandrill-api gem as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mandrill-api` gem is an officially-supported gem that uses the Mandrill API for sending. It's created and maintained by the Mandrill team, and is updated when the Mandrill API is updated because it's actually a part of the API creation process. Since it uses the API, you'll find all of the information about using it, including examples, in the [Mandrill API Docs](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/) (use the language selector in the upper right to choose Ruby for specific examples using the gem). If you want to use a template, you'd use the [messages/send-template API call](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=send-template) and specify the template as one of the parameters in the API call.

Looks like the `mandrill_mailer` gem is a third-party gem that uses ActionMailer over SMTP. So you'll be able to send messages using ActionMailer if you're already using ActionMailer, but you'll be limited to SMTP messages. If you're on a shared hosting provider or host that limits SMTP traffic, you may want to use the API. Most of the same options can be set over SMTP, though templates are going to be a bit more limited with SMTP because of length limits for SMTP headers, for example. SMTP is also asynchronous naturally, which is usually fine, but if you want the benefit of API errors being returned to you for smaller calls, for example, the API may be a better choice.

The API will also give you access to other methods besides sending, including retrieval of stats, setting up webhooks programmatically and other non-sending API calls, while SMTP is limited to sending. Ultimately, you should be able to send using either, so it's up to you which one works for your particular environment and needs.